# Columns in CSS take extra margin top, when margin is set to zero

Tags: html, css

There are three columns with varying widths, and stack-up side by side as expected but, the vertical alignment on the top is haphazard. The second column seems to always come in-between. I want the three columns to align vertically at the top.

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fy0otarj/)

```css
    #content{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
         display: inline-block;
    }

    #left{
        width: 40%;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #left p{
        display: inline;
    }

    #center{
        width: 20%;
    }

    #right{
        width: 30%;
    }

    .dinline{
       display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="content">
       <div id="left" class="dinline">
          <h1>Integer gravida nibh quis urna</h1>
          <h3>Augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum</h3>
          <p>
             Sed etiam vestibulum velit, euismod lacinia quam nisl id lorem. Quisque erat. Vestibulum pellentesque, justo mollis pretium suscipit, justo nulla blandit libero, in blandit augue justo quis nisl. Fusce mattis viverra elit. Fusce quis tortor. Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam pede erat, porta eu, lobortis eget lorem ipsum dolor. Donec placerat odio vel elit. Nullam ante orci, pellentesque eget, tempus quis, ultrices in, est. Curabitur sit amet nulla. Nam in massa. Sed vel tellus. Curabitur sem urna, consequat. Sed etiam vestibulum velit, euismod lacinia quam nisl id lorem. Quisque erat.
          </p>
          <button class="obutton">MORE DETAILS</button>
       </div>
       <div id="center" class="dinline">
          <h2>Feugiat Tempus</h2>
          <div class="img-thumb">
             <img src="" alt="">
             Donec leo, vivamus fermentum augue praesent a lacus at urna rutrum.
          </div>
          <div class="img-thumb">
             <img src="" alt="">
             Donec leo, vivamus fermentum augue praesent a lacus at urna rutrum.
          </div>
          <div class="img-thumb">
             <img src="" alt="">
             Donec leo, vivamus fermentum augue praesent a lacus at urna rutrum.
          </div>
       </div>
       <div id="right" class="dinline">
          <h3>Feugiat Tempus</h3>
          <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a><br>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Link to the question, please.

Comment: The link is at the top of your question.

Comment: You can use  vertical-align: top;  in #left, #right, and #center.
https://jsfiddle.net/9y7vxoj1/4/